# Uncaught Error: No module: app angularjs and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, angular-resource

I am new to angularjs I am trying simple app by referring some startup tutorials
When i run my app getting error as

`Uncaught Error: No module: app`

Here is my controller

**club-controller.js**

'use strict';

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('ClubsIndexController', ['$scope','Club','$routeParams', function($scope, Club, $routeParams){

    $scope.clubs = Club.query();
}])
```

**models.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');
app.factory('Club', function($resource){
    return $resource("clubs/:id", {id: '@id'},{
        index: {method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json'}
    });
})
```

**Here is my app.js.erb**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {controller: 'ClubIndexController', templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/index.html') %>'})
    }]);
```

I couldn't understand what is happening here. Can anyone help.

**Edit-1**

Changed my `application.js` file as

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require ../angular/app.js
//= require_tree ../angular
```

But now getting error as `Uncaught Error: No module: ngResource`

Comment: The code: `angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])` must run before any `var app = angular.module('app')`. Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Can you please check my edited question

Comment: You are probably using Angular 1.2, the `ngResource` module was moved to a separate file. Make sure you include `angular-resource.js` *after* `angular.js` but *before* your `app.js`.

Comment: Ya thats right it working fine now

Answer (score 1):

The `app.js` file must be included before `models.js` or `club-controller.js`.

The module definition `angular.module(name, [dependencies])` will create the module for you.  The other usages `angular.module(name)` will get the module, and expects it to have been defined with dependencies already.

Answer (score 0):

you have add in aplication.js require angular-resource.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource  
//= require ../angular/app.js
//= require_tree ../angular
```